# 12 hour format not sorting properly in Visualization Table

Tags: php, google-visualization

For my Visualization Table, i populated data from server side using PHP as guided by http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/php_example.html. I have two columns with time. Now i given 'string' type to this column and pass 12 hour format time. The response Json draw table properly. But sorting not works properly in 12 hour format.It sorts only depends on first two characters. It does not consider the am , pm.

I want to sort the am,pm time properly.I have tried to pass 24 hour format data from server and receive it javascirpt and try to format the time. But It is also not works properly.Please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: How about separating your result in 2 arrays, one for am hours and one for pm hours and then sorting ? maybe post some of your sorting code so we can help you out better?

Comment: function drawTable() {
    var username="Raja";
    var curdate="19/03/2012";
  
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
     url: "cltable.php",
      data:{'name':username,'date':curdate},
     dataType:"json",
     async: false
     }).responseText;
     
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    console.log(jsonData);
    var timetabledata1 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('commontables'));
    timetabledata1.draw(data, { 'backgroundColor':'transparent'}); 
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function drawTable() {
          var username="Raja";
          var curdate="19/03/2012";

          var jsonData = $.ajax({
              url: "cltable.php",
               data:{'name':username,'date':curdate},
              dataType:"json",
              async: false
              }).responseText;

          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
          console.log(jsonData);
          var timetabledata1 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('commontables'));
          timetabledata1.draw(data, { 'backgroundColor':'transparent'}); 
    }
```

**My PHP Scritp to populate Data:**

```
    $colarray=array(array("id"=>"ent","label"=>"Entry_time","pattern"=>"","type"=>"datetime"),array('id'=>"ext","label"=>"Exit_time","pattern"=>"","type"=>"datetime"));
    $table['cols']=$colarray;                                                    
for($i=0;$i<$customersnum;$i++)
    {
   $prefinal[$i]=array("c"=>array(array("v"=>$entry_time[$i]),array("v"=>$exit_time[$i])));
    }  
     $table['rows']=$prefinal;
     echo json_encode($table);
```